# Moderators for beta. How does it work?

Tags: support, moderators

I'm not too familiar with the process, so hopefully someone can clarify here. Do we need any moderators for the public beta, which seems to be coming up in less than 2 days? Will members of the official StackExchange team act as temporary moderators during this beta?

Comment: There are already members of the SE team who have moderator powers, but I don't think they participate heavily in the site. If I remember correctly from other beta sites I've participated in, at some point during the public beta, about a week after we go public, temporary moderators will be chosen from the community, and then later on toward the end of the beta period, there will be a choice of permanent moderators made by the SE team with community input.

Comment: @David: Thanks. That sounds about right. (At least from my experience with other Area 51 sites too, not that I really followed it.) If you posted it as an answer, I'd accept it!

Comment: Ah, I thought this was going to be a moderator nomination thread ;-) but I guess it is a bit early for that. I'll post an answer with details.

Comment: @David: Oh no... well, that wasn't my intention at least. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are already members of the SE team who are registered on the site and have moderator powers, but I don't think they participate heavily in the site.

The moderator-choosing process is described in e.g. this [post on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57986/how-to-organize-a-formal-moderator-election-on-a-beta-se-site/58056#58056) but here's the gist: about a week after the public beta starts, temporary moderators will be chosen by the Stack Exchange team, based on community input. Then later on, after the end of the beta period, there will be an election of permanent moderators - or rather, an election of moderator *candidates* to indicate who the community prefers, but I'm sure the results will be reviewed by the SE team and the final choice is up to them.

Comment: Thanks, that's the clarification I was looking for.

Comment: Actually "election of permanent (or rather, 'official') moderators" happens 30 days *after* the end of beta, not "toward".

Comment: Thanks, fixed. (That wasn't described in the MSO post and I thought on other sites there had been permanent moderator elections before the beta period expired.)

Comment: The original *intention* was the launch the site (graduate) with the new moderators already elected. But, upon reflection, many users would not be using the site until *after* the beta and we wanted to give everyone a chance to run and elect the Moderators. Hence, the change to holding elections *after* the end of beta.

Comment: @RobertC So during beta it will only be diamond and moderators by "score"? I am not begging, but I would love the job of editing question titles (and body text, where needed) to rephrase them in standard English. You see these on SO, SU and others all the time: "How to get color of pixel?" and "Modular question?" This is one great item that makes the sites less professional and polished than they could be. So, we could create the post of Designated English Policeman.

Comment: And Re: Those example questions, actually, I am surprised that so many of these questions on SO, Pr, and elsewhere still survive in butchered form, even though sometimes moderators edit the body text.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is time for an [election](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/100/97)